# Airbyte Sync failed - process exited with non-zero exit code 125

Tags: azure, airbyte

My Airbyte docker image installation on Azure VM went fine, but while executing sync from any database , facing this issue
Anyone faced similar?

```
Failure reason: Something went wrong within the source connector
Source process exited with non-zero exit code 125
platform > readFromSource: source exception
121
io.airbyte.workers.internal.exception.SourceException: Source process exited with non-zero exit code 125
io.airbyte.workers.internal.exception.DestinationException: Destination process exited with non-zero exit code 125
source > docker: Error response from daemon: Range of CPUs is from 0.01 to 1.00, as there are only 1 CPUs available.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, a problem with the configuration of the image in Azure VM. Airbyte proposes guidelines for this issue at https://docs.airbyte.com/deploying-airbyte/on-azure-vm-cloud-shell. Probably you can find your solution there. Keep an eye on what they suggest. Though they say that *"The instructions have been tested on a standard DS1 v2 (1 vcpu, 3.5 GiB memory) Microsoft Azure VM with Ubuntu 18.04."*, you should try by **scaling it up** to be sure it will support the workload.

Note that Airbyte creates additional resources (containers) when new connectors are added in the pipelines. So, it would require to monitor the performance.

Comment: Yup I followed recommended configuration from airbyte doc earlier, so I had DS2 VM

Comment: Yes, they suggest the minimal, running configuration. So, you will always need more for a secure production performance. I suggest you to run some tests in your local environment (using Docker and monitoring the resources it consumes) before deploying to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:
After ignoring misleading error messages, I looked at docker daemon response

I spin up other B series VM with 2 vcpus, 8 gb ram and it did solve the problem
(Azure B2ms Ubuntu VM)